# One-Dimensional Subsets of Hilbert Space vs. Euclidean Space

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

Motivated by a question I received (though a bit different), is there a one-dimensional subset of Hilbert Space that cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Here, dimension refers to covering or inductive dimension.  I know by the Menger-Nobeling Theorem that any compact, one-dimensional subset of Hilbert Space can be embedded in three-space, but compactifications of Hilbert Space are not something I've studied.

It feels like it might be equivalent to ask if the Hilbert Space and Hilbert *Cube* can be distinguished by their one-dimensional subsets, as well.  Curious to know the answer to either!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  It is a generalization of the above-stated Menger-Nobeling Theorem, given as theorem V.3 in Hurewicz/Wallman, that the assumption of compactness may be dropped.  In other words, any separable metric space of dimension $n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.